# Generalized Subset Design with constraints in python

Tags: python, experimental-design

I have three factors `F1, F2, F3` with `3, 3, 6` corresponding levels and I want to limit the number of their combination for experimental design.

As far as I have seen by searching, this can be done with `pyDOE2` Generalized Subset Design like:

```
import pyDOE2

levels = [3, 3, 6]
reduction = 3
result = pyDOE2.gsd(levels, reduction)
result.data.tolist()
>>>[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 5],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 4],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 5],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [2, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 5],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [2, 2, 1],
 [2, 2, 4]]
```

However, what I would like to do is to set some constraints on the possible combinations of the factors levels. For example, I don't want combinations that include F1L1 with F2L3 or F2L1 with F3L2 (F for factor and L for level). Is there a way to get the optimal reduced combinations taking in consideration these constraints?

This is not a pyDOE2 specific question (any other library which can achieve this would be ok) but I would like to do it with python.

Comment: why not create more combinations and drop combinations you are not interested?

Comment: Because this way the levels may not appear equal number of times. The distribution may break.